# Bulk copy with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Boto3 has a managed copy method, which works pretty nicely for individual objects. Similarly, it seems to have a `delete()` method that works on a collection.  But if I have a collection of objects (see `objects` below), it seems like the only way I can do a bulk operation is to use my own thread/process pool (I'm using multiprocessing for simplicity, but concurrent.futures would likely be better for error handling).

```
import boto3
import multiprocessing

bucket_name = '1000genomes'
prefix = 'changelog_details/'
bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_name)
objects = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix).limit(30)
sources = [{'Bucket': o.bucket_name, 'Key': o.key} for o in objects]

target_bucket = 'my-bucket'  # fill in bucket here!

def copy_to_bucket(src, bucket=target_bucket):
    # client is not thread-safe according to docs
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    return s3.meta.client.copy(src, bucket, src['Key'])

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(20)
results = pool.map(copy_to_bucket, sources)
print('Copied %d results' % len(results))
```

Have I missed something about how to do this in bulk? I was attempting to look through the aws-cli codebase and/or the S3Transfer class, but both of them seem to be focused on uploading or downloading files.

Failing that, any thoughts on whether threads or processes are the better choice here? (I'd think the majority of a server-side copy would be just waiting for network I/O regardless).

Comment: The underlying S3 service API supports a multi-object delete operation but not one for copy, which *might* explain why one has native support but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this problem a while ago and while I was preparing to work on it I wrote this [DesignDoc](https://github.com/0xMH/s3-migrator/blob/main/DesignDoc.md).

Threads will be your best fried here cause this's an I/O problem. I wrote my implementation of concurrent copying in s3 on [S3-migrator](https://github.com/0xMH/s3-migrator/blob/main/DesignDoc.md). Also I needed to keep a state of what files I'm copying and used mysql for that due to our usage.

Answer (score 0):

Good news! [S3 supports batch operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops.html), which includes copying objects in bulk. Like normal, you will create a [Python S3Control client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3control.html) and use the `create_job` method.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3control')
response = client.create_job()
```

As usual, the tricky part is providing the correct parameters into the `create_job` method. Rely on [this document](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3control/client/create_job.html) for starters, but a few things to note:

1. `Operation` will either be `S3PutObjectCopy`, which specifies the action applied to every object listed in the manifest.
2. The `Manifest` is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-create-job.html#specify-batchjob-manifest) and supports CSV and [S3 Inventory formats](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html).
3. You may need to spend some time working out the AccessControlGrants that will allow for cross-domain copying, but this example should get you started.

Here's an example that would perform a bulk copy of all objects listed in a provided manifest within source `foobucket` to destination bucket `barbucket.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3control')

# specify the S3 Inventory Manifest details
manifest = {
    'Spec': {
        'Format': 'S3InventoryReport_CSV_20161130',
        'Fields': [
            'Bucket',
            'Key',
            'Size',
            'LastModifiedDate',
            'ETag',
            'StorageClass',
            'IsMultipartUploaded',
            'ReplicationStatus'
        ]
    },
    'Location': {
        'Bucket': 'foobucket',
        'Prefix': 'inventory',
        'Format': 'CSV'
    }
}

# create the job to copy objects
response = client.create_job(
    AccountId='123456789012', # your AWS account ID
    Operation={
        'S3PutObjectCopy': {
            'TargetResource': 'arn:aws:s3:::barbucket',
            'MetadataDirective': 'COPY'
            # add AccessControlGrants here
        }
    },
    Report={
        'Bucket': 'barbucket',
        'Prefix': 'report',
        'Format': 'CSV'
    },
    Manifest=manifest
)
```

This method returns a job_id String, which you can use to track the progress of the job using `client.describe_job()`.